# How do I join an array with the result not being a string in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have an array `[1,2,3,4,5,6]` and a separator `'~'` and I want to joint them into a new array with `'~'` being the separator.

I'd like the output to be `[1,'~', 2,'~', 3,'~', 4,'~', 5,'~', 6]`.

Using [Lodash](https://lodash.com/) I got something like:

```
var my_array = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
var separator = '~'
_.flatten(_.zip(my_array, new Array(my_array.length).fill(separator)))
```

But this feels ugly and I'm sure there is a better way.

EDIT: Even though the array above has `int`s I'd like this to work for any type of object.

Comment: Why not just a nice simple loop?

Comment: A nice simple loop will do the trick, but will mandate a manual `-1` in the length. Was looking for something a little more pretty.

Comment: *"...but will mandate a manual -1 in the length..."* Huh?

Comment: `join` is an ugly operation to implement because it has an inherent break of the symmetry.

Comment: @AurSaraf what do you mean by break of the symmetry?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder in order for this to be actually simple the loop will have to run for `my_array.length - 1` times. No?

Comment: The question has been closed, but a single line ES6 would be: `var r = Array.from({ length: (a.length * 2) - 1 }, (v, i) => i % 2 ? s : a[i/2] );` Where `a` is your array and `s` is your "~". Codepen: http://codepen.io/cjke/pen/pejPOQ?editors=0010

Comment: I'm a bit bored - here is an even shorter one: `var r = a.reduce((c, v) => [...c, v, s], []).slice(0, -1)` Codepen: http://codepen.io/cjke/pen/WpQPKz?editors=0010

Comment: @AgamRafaeli I mean it does something to all of the array values *but one*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nice simple `forEach` without a dozen temporary arrays, etc.:

```js
var my_array = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
var result = [my_array[0]];
my_array.forEach(function(entry, index) {
  if (index > 0) {
    result.push("~", entry);
  }
});
console.log(result);
```

Or you can get rid of the `if` with a single temporary array:

```js
var my_array = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
var result = [my_array[0]];
my_array.slice(1).forEach(function(entry, index) {
  result.push("~", entry);
});
console.log(result);
```

Comment: FTW!! Thank you!!

Comment: @AgamRafaeli: It does assume at least one entry in the array, so if that assumption is invalid, the `var result...` line becomes `var result = my_array.length ? [my_array[0]] : [];` :-)

Answer (score 8):

Why not in pue Javascript:

**Minor Update:** *to account for values greater then 9*

- first join it to a string `my_array.join("~")`
- then split every char `.split(/\b/gi)`

```js
var my_array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,10,11]
var separator = '~'

console.info(my_array.join("~").split(/\b/gi));
```

**Update (even if closed):**

In Regard to point, other Objects. This should work, even if not a one-liner.

```js
var myArray = [1,2,3,45,6,10,new Date()];

var newArray = myArray.reduce((p,n)=>{ 
  if(p.length){
    p.push("~");
  }
  p.push(n);
  return p;
},[]);

console.info(newArray)
```

Comment: And it blows up as soon as there's a `10` or higher in the array, or a value less than `0`, or something other than a number, or, or, or...

Comment: Also, it assumes a good toString implementation for each of the objects.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder now it should work with 10 and higher

Comment: This fails if the array is not toString-able for example dates.

Comment: It's still a horrible way to approach this with lots of other failure modes (including those negative numbers I mentioned).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder if you change comments,it is impossible to answer correctly to one.

Comment: Un huh, that was 10 minutes before your update (and obvious).

Answer (score 3):

Just throwing my hat in:

```
arr.map(x => [x, '~']).reduce((p, c) => p.concat(c));
```

This isn't very hacky, it maps every element into two elements and concats them together, it is pretty easy to generalize:

```
const intercalate = (arr, sep) => arr.map(x => [x, sep])
                                     .reduce((p, c) => p.concat(c))
                                     .slice(0, -1);
```

Or with a single reduce:

```
const intercalate = (arr, sep) => arr.reduce((p, c) => p.concat(c, sep)).slice(0, -1);
```

Comment: for `arr = [1,2,3]` this returns `[1, "~", 2, "~", 3, "~"]`. Maybe add slice(0,-1) at the end?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option using `forEach` -

```
var a = [1,2,3]
var sep = '~'
var b = []
a.forEach(function(x) { b.push(x, sep) })
b.pop() // remove the last `~`
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [_.flatMap](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#flatMap),

```
var my_array = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
var separator = '~';
console.log(_.flatMap(my_array, function( v ){ return [v,separator] }).slice(0,-1));
```

**Update:**

Ensure trailing `~` is removed.

Comment: This will leave trailing `~`

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and concat a tilde if necessary.

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    result = array.reduce(function (r, a, i) {
        return r.concat(i ? '~' : [], a);
    }, []);
    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Anosther proposal with [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    result = [];

array.forEach(function (a) {
   result.push(a, '~');
});

result.length--;
    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: All those unnecessary temporary arrays!!

Answer (score 0):

Using a traditional `for` loop

```js
var nums = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
var dash = '~';

var res = [];
for (var i=0; i<nums.length; i++){
  res.push(nums[i]);
  res.push(dash);
}
res.pop();

console.log(res);
```

Comment: This as of now results in [1, "~", 2, "~", 3, "~", 4, "~", 5, "~", 6, "~"] where the desired result [1, "~", 2, "~", 3, "~", 4, "~", 5, "~", 6]

Comment: Sorry,  corrected.